# Hosting React and Express on Cloud

Tags: reactjs

Is there a free cloud hosting for ReactJS with Express application? What I mean is that I have a frontend using ReactJS and the database connection information is at Express. I am wondering if there are any free cloud hosting for ReactJS with Express? It is for a very small application for testing purposes. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase hosting you can host the production build for free , you can also use google cloud storage or directly on google cloud compute engine , the f1-micro machine is free to use